# C# Byref method

Tags: c#

Ok i am still having problems here:
My code looks like this:

```
public static void Init_grablistFile(string grabListPath)
    {
        int compt = 0;
        string List_grablist = "";
        var line = File.ReadAllLines(grabListPath);
        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            if (line[i].Contains("="))
            {
                string[] var_temp = line[i].Split(new Char[] {'='});
                ResizeArray(GlobalVars.tab_grablist, new int[] { compt + 1, 2 });
                GlobalVars.tab_grablist[compt, 0] = var_temp[0];
                GlobalVars.tab_grablist[compt, 1] = var_temp[1];
                //Console.WriteLine(GlobalVars.tab_grablist[compt, 0]);
                //Console.WriteLine(GlobalVars.tab_grablist[compt, 1]);

            }
            else
            {
                if (List_grablist == "")
                {
                    List_grablist = line[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    List_grablist = List_grablist + "|" + line[i];
                }
            }
        }
        //LoadTableFromString(ref GlobalVars.Table_Grablist, ref List_grablist);
    }
    public static void LoadTableFromString(ref string[] table, ref string sString, bool cleanup = false)
    {
        table = sString.Split(new Char[] { '|' });
        if (cleanup)
        {
            sString = "";
        }
    }
    private static Array ResizeArray(Array arr, int[] newSizes)
    {
        if (newSizes.Length != arr.Rank)
            throw new ArgumentException("arr must have the same number of dimensions " +
                                        "as there are elements in newSizes", "newSizes");

        var temp = Array.CreateInstance(arr.GetType().GetElementType(), newSizes);
        int length = arr.Length <= temp.Length ? arr.Length : temp.Length;
        Array.ConstrainedCopy(arr, 0, temp, 0, length);
        return temp;
    }
```

And my 2 global vars are:

```
public static string[,] tab_grablist = new string[1, 2];
    public static string[] Table_Grablist;
```

When i call Init_grablist i get an error that Global.tab_grablist throws an exception.
I have no idea what is going on. Any ideas?

Edited to update code.

Comment: _What error do you get?_

Comment: The best overloaded method match for LoadTableFromString(ref string[], ref string, bool) has some invalid arguments.

Comment: The array should not be `ref`.

Comment: I'm a VB programmer, but with your current sample code `table` could actually be an `out` rather than a `ref` parameter, I believe.

Comment: My problem is to the resize array. I added console write to every updated array and it work. However if i call a simple consolewrite of the GlobalVars.Table_grablist after this function is called i get error. I am trying to redim the array. Anyone is understanding what is going on? The problem must be within the resizearray function

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `ref` in the `LoadTableFromString` method call, or remove `ref` from the first parameter of `LoadTableFromString` declaration, e.g. call this way given your current code.

```
LoadTableFromString(ref GlobalVars.Table_Grablist, ref List_grablist);
```

or declare method this way:

```
public static void LoadTableFromString(string[] table, ref string sString, bool cleanup = false)
```

Also, you should put a check for `null` on `table` and `sString`, and see which of these is coming as `null` for future proofing.

Comment: Hell, this means i have been working for hours. Maybe i should go get some rest.

Sorry for this pointless question people.
Cheers

Comment: The point of SO is to do your own research before you ask a question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx It is not a foolish question, but it didn't need to be asked.